# Only Regex part is failing to retrieve in e-mail

Tags: javascript, html, regex, jenkins, email-ext

I want to retrieve this from Jenkins build log by using regex.

**OutPut:**

```
======================================================
elapsed:  18.09 | threads:    5 | thread time: 65.80 
features:     2 | ignored:    1 | efficiency: 0.73
scenarios:   18 | passed:    18 | failed: 0
======================================================
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-info">
    <span  style ="COLOR: #8B0000; ">${BUILD_LOG_REGEX,regex="^.*?======================================================.*?$",linesAfter=3, maxMatches=1, showTruncatedLines=false}
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Output:

```
======================================================
elapsed:  18.09 | threads:    5 | thread time: 65.80 
features:     2 | ignored:    1 | efficiency: 0.73
scenarios:   18 | passed:    18 | failed: 0
======================================================
```

You can use this RegExp to get the above output:

```
^={0,54}(\n.*){1,3}\n={0,54}
```

**Note:**
If stats are in the middle of the sentence exclude the `^` in the regular expression.

Comment: Expression is ok but i am not getting the content in E Mail, In E Mail I am getting only the div containers which have not regex expressions..

Comment: which module you are using to parse the HTML content like handlebars?